Tool for training opening moves
I have a PGN with the best moves against common opening traps.  I'd like to train my memory and use an app/website.
The idea is that computer chooses a random line on the PGN and I have to remember the correct response.
I'm sure a tool like this must exist but don't know how to search for it.

A number of similar and related tools have been featured on The Perpetual Chess Podcast.
Tools
lichess.org Study: Upload or create PGN files to create your own studies for free. Each study may have several chapters. Select "Practice with Computer" to play through variations.

Chessable.com: This is a popular chess trainer that leverages spaced repetition. Tends to excel for tactics and/or opening lines. Select Random Variations as the setting for the "Review" parameter.

Digital Flashcards: Anki allows you to create flashcards with chess positions (example). Users have the option to use spaced repetition.
Related:
Is there a free online chess repertoire tool?
